# Get all possible values from a string array that contains two strings c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, contains, directory

Hi people of the world.

I'm a beginner C# programmer and I have na array with lots of filePaths from this directory:

```
'C:\ProgramData\folder1\fodler2\folder3\'
```

The array is something like this:

```
string[] arrays = {'C:\ProgramData\folder1\fodler2\folder3\sw2-client1-propose1-measure1.dbf', 'C:\ProgramData\folder1\fodler2\folder3\sw-client1-propose2-measure1.dbf', 'C:\ProgramData\folder1\fodler2\folder3\sw1-client1-propose2-measure2.dbf', 'C:\ProgramData\folder1\fodler2\folder3\sw1-client1-propose2-measure1.dbf' }
```

With this exemple you can see that the files in the array have the structure:

```
sw-client-propose-measure.dbf
```

Where:

```
sw - a string meaning the name of the software used to get the values to the database
client - the ID of clients
propose - the ID of proposes
measure - the ID of measure
```

Now I need to get a array with all the paths that have a specific propose ID and a sw name that are in the string arrays.

Can you help me achieve my results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Comment: I would look into a couple options. If you want to keep everything in an array, I would look into using regex expressions against the array values. The other option would be represent the data outside of an array.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the best code to get what I need :(, I've search all over the web na I couldn't find anything related to this...

Comment: I don't know if an array would be the best option to be honest. I think converting the array to a defined class or list might be better. You could then use linq to search for values. JSON is another possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution of my problem:

```
string[] filtered = file.ToList().Where(s => s.Contains("propose ID")).ToArray();
string[] superfiltered = filtered.ToList().Where(r => r.Contains("sw")).ToArray();
```

Special thank to @Padmanaban Gokula

Answer (score 0):

This will work,

```
string[] filtered = arrays.ToList().Where(s=>s.Contains("proposeID")).ToArray();
```